# How to serialize double value when calling soap service in android?

Tags: android

I am having one web service and I have call that from the Android application by passing double value along with other values like String, int and float. When i call the web service I am getting Runtime exception saying cannot serialize the double value. Please some one help me to do call the web service if you know the solution.

Thanks and Regards,
Rajapandian.K

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope you got some solution for this problem, I am giving one solution which i got to solve this problem if you want you can use it. If you are using KSOAP2 to consume web service, please check something called KVMSerialization to send object as a parameter.

And to send double value as request parameter, please use Marshaling concept, refer the link find below:

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html